# Is that an attributive clause?

Tags: clauses

I see a long sentence in the webpage

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1691493/000169149316000002/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml

In the bottom line:

> This undertaking does not affect any limits Section 102(a) of the
> National Securities Markets Improvement Act of 1996  "NSMIA")
> [Pub. L. No. 104-290, 110 Stat. 3416 (Oct. 11, 1996)]
> imposes on the ability of States to require information.

Make it simple:

> This undertaking does not affect the Act imposes on the ability of States to require information.

The "imposes on the ability of States to require information" is an attributive clause or not?

Then I can add a  word "which" :

> This undertaking does not affect the Act which imposes on the ability of States to require information.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplification has removed an essential item "any limits"

> This undertaking does not affect any limits the Act imposes on the ability of States to require information.

The required object of "affect" is "any limits", and not "the Act".

The phrase "the Act imposes... information" is a relative clause that modifies "limits".  You could insert "that" or "which" (American English would, I believe, tend to use "that")

> ... does not affect any limits that the Act imposes ...

And it means that you can't interpret this undertaking to allow a state to do collect information in a way that the Act makes unlawful.

Answer (score 1):

> *This undertaking does not affect any limits* [(*that/which*) *Section*
> *102(a) of the National Securities Markets Improvement Act of 1996*
> *("NSMIA") [Pub. L. No. 104-290, 110 Stat. 3416 (Oct. 11, 1996)]*
> *imposes on the ability of States to require information*].

The expression in square brackets is a relative clause modifying "limits".

"That" or "which" could be inserted, as shown.

Grammatically, it could be shortened to:

> *This undertaking does not affect any limits [(that/which) the Act*
> *imposes on the ability of States to require information].*

Here, again, the expression in square brackets is a relative clause modifying "limits".